# qualified-id in declaration before '(' token

Tags: c++

This is some crazy error and is giving me a lot of trouble.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Book {
private:
    int bookid;
    char bookname[50];
    char authorname[50];
    float cost;

public:
    void getinfo(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << "Enter Book ID" <<endl;
            cin >> bookid;

            cout << "Enter Book Name" << endl;
            cin >> bookname;
            cout << "Enter Author Name" << endl;
            cin >> authorname;
            cout << "Enter Cost" << endl;
            cin >> cost;
        }
    }

    void displayinfo(void);

};


int main()
{
    Book bk[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        bk[i].getinfo();
    }

    void Book::displayinfo() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << bk[i].bookid;
            cout << bk[i].bookname;
            cout << bk[i].authorname;
            cout << bk[i].cost;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error, as noted in the title is expected declaration before '}' token at the line void Book::displayinfo() in main

Also this error is coming expected '}' at end of input

Comment: You can't define `void Book::displayinfo()` inside `main`. Member function definitions belong in the scope where the class is defined. In this case, global scope.

Comment: Move the definition of `void Book::displayinfo(){` out of the `main()` body. Also your formatting indentaton can be improved.

Comment: Very interesting. What is your question?

Comment: @StoryTeller why should member function definitions belong in the scope where the class is defined?

Comment: @StoryTeller cant we use void ::Book::displayinfo() {} for defining the member function inside the main

Comment: @rimiro - Because that's how the language is designed.

Comment: @StoryTeller it seems like we cant even use void ::Book::displayinfo() {} for defining the member function inside the main. Why is it so?

Comment: @rimiro - I already told you why

Answer (score 14):

Move the function definition `void Book::displayinfo(){}` out of the `main()`.

Along with this, i have some more suggestion for you. Update your class definition like this

```
class Book{
private:
  int bookid;
  string bookname; // char bookname[50]; because it can accept book name length more than 50 character. 
  string authorname; // char authorname[50]; because it can accept authorname length more than 50 character. 
  float cost;

public:
    void getinfo(void){
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            cout << "Enter Book ID" <<endl;
            cin >> bookid;

            cout << "Enter Book Name" << endl;
            getline(cin,bookname); // Because book name can have spaces.
            cout << "Enter Author Name" << endl;
            getline(cin,authorname); // Because author name can have spaces too.
            cout << "Enter Cost" << endl;
            cin >> cost;

        }
    }

    void displayinfo(void);

};
```

Comment: I also get this error, and my function definition is not inside main()...

Comment: Also, OP's implementation of `displayinfo` is wrong, referring to a nonexistent `bk` array.  And if you're handing out advice, tell OP not to refer to `cin` and `cout` in class member functions. Instead, pass the relevant `ostream`s and `istream`s in as parameters instead.